# ARIMAX- Do exogenous variables have to be stationary?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, stationarity

I am trying to model a time series with R using the `auto.arima()` function. I understand there is no need for the autoregressive variable to be stationary as this is taken care of by the "integrated" part. However, when extending the model with exogenous variables using `xreg`, does the same rule apply to them, or do I have to transform those to achieve stationarity prior to including in the model?

Comment: @RobHyndman says [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) (section "Non-stationary data") that it is indeed necessary to difference both the time series itself and the series of regressors, which surprises me.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i checked but when mentioning all variables to be stationary he is actually referring to an ARMA model. someone commented with exact my question and Rob Hyndman suggested to post the question here on CrossValidated. Hence I am still unclear, appreciate if somebody could shed some light on this.

Comment: Your first sentence is not quite correct (it *is* necessary for the data to be $d$ differences away from stationarity, which is not true of all nonstationary processes). When you have exogenous regressors, it's the residuals from the regression that have to be ARIMA (so must be stationary after $d$ differences), not either the endogenous or exogeneous data.

Comment: `auto.arima`, `Arima` and `arima` functions in R fit regression with ARMA errors, not ARIMAX. [There is a difference](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) between the them. Therefore, I suggest you edit your title to remove the term *ARIMAX*. Also, please use capital letters where appropriate, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you do not need to difference non-stationary data before running an ARIMAX model. However, if Y is non-stationary and/or any of the regressors are nonstationary (and you do not difference), you need to be very careful that you are not fitting a spurious regression. One way to check is to keep the `order=c(0,0,0)` in the Arima model and check the residuals for a unit root. Something like:

```
fit_OLS <- Arima(Y,order=c(0,0,0),xreg=X)
checkresiduals(fit_OLS)
library(urca)
summary(ur.df(residuals(fit_OLS)))
```

If the residuals have a unit root, you have a spurious regression, and you should difference both Y and X before re-running the regression (alternatively, you can set the AR(p) term >=1, see slide 17 here: [https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/jeeslides.pdf](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/jeeslides.pdf)). If the residuals from this regression don't have a unit root, but *both* X and Y do have a unit root, then they are likely cointegrated and you can run an [error correction model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_model).

In the Arima function from the forecast package, if you set `Arima(Y,order=c(p,1,q),xreg=X)` where p and q are integers for the number of AR and MA terms, it will difference *both* Y and X.

If you only want to difference Y, but not X, you will need to do it manually:

```
DY <- diff(Y)
X_short <- X[2:length(X)]
Arima(DY,order=c(0,0,0),xreg=X_short)
```

If you find that these residuals have a unit root (and DY doesn't, but X does) then you should difference X and refit, also adding ARMA(p,q) terms if appropriate. If the residuals don't have a unit root, you can keep the set-up as-is, adding ARMA(p,q) terms as appropriate.

If you only want to difference X, but not Y,

```
Y_short <- Y[2:length(Y)]
DX <- diff(X)
Arima(Y_short,order=c(0,0,0),xreg=DX)
```

again checking to ensure the residuals do not have a unit root before adding the appropriate ARMA(p,q) terms.

Finally, note that in the `Arima` function, the default is to include an intercept when `d=0` and not when `d=1` (in which case the intercept is a drift term). If you know you always want to include an intercept, you should use the `include.constant=TRUE` option in the `Arima` function.